# Conditional operator. Error CS0266 Cannot implicitly convert type 'int' to 'byte'

Tags: c#, type-conversion

I need some help on this conversion.
I have decompiled an old dll file, because I need some small changes and I do not have the original sourcecode, but before I start making these changes I would like the original code to compile.

I only got one issue:

> Error CS0266  Cannot implicitly convert type 'int' to 'byte'. An
>   explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

I have tried many different solutions but all of the fails, so please help.
How to fix this conversion?

```
public static byte SqlGetByte(DbDataReader sr, int col, ConnectionString connection)
{
    return (sr[col] == DBNull.Value) ? 0 : (connection.OraDb ? Convert.ToByte(sr.GetDecimal(col)) : sr.GetByte(col));
}
```

Comment: It is because of the data type inconsistency between SQL and C#.You can verify what is the value which is getting returned from database for "col" using GetFieldType() method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just cast to `byte`

```
return (byte)((sr[col] == DBNull.Value) ? 0 : (connection.OraDb ? Convert.ToByte(sr.GetDecimal(col)) : sr.GetByte(col)));

// or

return (sr[col] == DBNull.Value) ? (byte)0 : (connection.OraDb ? Convert.ToByte(sr.GetDecimal(col)) : sr.GetByte(col));
```

---

From the specs

[12.15 Conditional operator](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/Ecma-334.pdf)

> ... A conditional expression of the form b ? x : y first evaluates the
>   condition b
>   ...
>
> The second and third operands, x and y, of the ?: operator control the
>   type of the conditional expression.
>
> - If x has type X and y has type Y then,
>
>   - If X and Y are the same type, then this is the type of the conditional expression.
>   - Otherwise, if an implicit conversion (§11.2) exists from X to Y, but not from Y to X, then Y is the type of the conditional expression.
>   - Otherwise, if an implicit enumeration conversion (§11.2.4) exists from X to Y, then Y is the type of the conditional expression.
>   - Otherwise, if an implicit enumeration conversion (§11.2.4) exists from Y to X, then X is the type of the conditional expression.
>   - Otherwise, if an implicit conversion (§11.2) **exists from Y to X, but not from X to Y**, then **X is the type of the conditional expression**.
>   - Otherwise, no expression type can be determined, and a compile-time error occurs.
> - If only one of x and y has a type, and both x and y are implicitly convertible to that type, then that is the type of the conditional
>     expression.
> - Otherwise, no expression type can be determined, and a compile-time error occurs.

**Given**

```
return condition ? x(int) : y(condition ? x2(byte)) : y2(byte));
```

**Example**

```
byte y = 123;
int x = 234;

x = y; // y can implicitly convert to x
y = x; // error, x cant implicitly convert to y
```

In summary, the resulting type of the *Conditional Operator* wants to be an `int` and you are returning a `byte` from your method. Computer says no... At the very least you will need to cast somewhere

Answer (score 1):

If `sr[col] == DBNull.Value` equates to true, you are returning 0 whereas the method returns a `byte`.

Change it to:

```
return (sr[col] == DBNull.Value) ? Convert.ToByte(0) : (connection.OraDb ? Convert.ToByte(sr.GetDecimal(col)) : sr.GetByte(col));
```